# How to remove border from ngx-datatables?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I want to remove the last-child border from the ngx-datatables. I have tried doing the trick using CSS but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way to remove border from the last child?

Thanks.

Code I'm currently using to display datatables:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-block table-border-style customer-card-table">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <ngx-datatable #myTable class="dark" [rows]="rows" [columnMode]="'force'"
                [headerHeight]="50" [footerHeight]="50" [rowHeight]="40" [scrollbarH]="true"
                [sorts]="[{prop: 'name', dir: 'desc'},{prop: 'email', dir: 'desc'}]">
                <ngx-datatable-column name="ID">
                    <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                        {{row._id}} {{row._id}}
                    </ng-template>
                </ngx-datatable-column>
            </ngx-datatable>
        </div><!-- End of DataTables -->
    </div><!-- End of Card Block-->
</div><!-- End of Card -->
```

Comment: Can you please share an example of your code so we can have a look?

Comment: try it inside styles.css not component css

Comment: @Dominik I have.

Comment: @pc_coder I did. Still didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

The border thing is located on the datatable-footer so you can use this class to remove the border

```
.ngx-datatable.material .datatable-footer {border-top: none}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this code but it doesn't work: https://prnt.sc/u5h5hz

Comment: We can make the selector more specific so may be we can override the class. You can target it by id or class like `#myTable.ngx-datatable.material .datatable-footer

Comment: Didn't worked again. I don't think it has anything to do with the footer. Because I have already removed the footer and the border is coming from row's bottom not top. This is where the border is coming from: https://prnt.sc/u5hgpg

Comment: If If I do something like this: .ngx-datatable .datatable-body-row { border-bottom: none; } It removes the border from all the rows, not the last row specifically which was the reason for asking the question.

Comment: This is because it perhaps has no child. Any leads on how to fix this?